# Using Pillow to center multi-line text without it going off the image

Tags: python, image-processing, automation, python-imaging-library

For context, I am trying to make a 'sigma-male' meme generator. The idea is I can feed in a load of pre-defined 'sigma-male' jokes/quotes and overaly it on an image of a 'sigma-male'. The format of these pictures should be that in the center of the image there will be a line saying 'Sigma-Male Rule #X' and underneath there would be some bad life advice e.g. 'Don't be part of the problem, be the whole problem'.
Here is the picture I am starting with (note that for my purposes all images are the same size, 1080x1080. So issues of variable image size shouldn't be a problem):

[Image of character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRbqb.jpg)

But when I try to add the 'life-advice' I end up with this:
[Character with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPRzW.jpg)

As you can see, the text runs straight off of the image. One fix I have tried is by breaking it up into several lines: [Character with text after breaking line up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBU16.jpg)

Theoretically, this could be useful but the problem is I would manually have to adjust each different quote, which would stop this from being an automatic procedure.

Ideally, what I would like is an image like this: [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i59gw.jpg)

Something else I would need to account for is if I have a short quote that's only one line, how can I also guarentee that this will be centered appropriatley relative to the 'Sigma Male Rule#X

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap

my_image = Image.open("Bateman1Raw resized.jpg")
title_font = ImageFont.truetype('Bebas-Regular.ttf', 100)


title_text = "Sigma Male Rule #1"
text_test='Don\'t be part of the\n problem, be the whole problem'


image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((200,400), title_text, (255, 255, 255), font=title_font,stroke_width=2,stroke_fill='black')
image_editable.text((0,500), words,(255, 255, 255),align='center',font=title_font,stroke_width=2,stroke_fill='black')

my_image.save("result.jpg")
```

Comment: And Pillow doesn't split text on `'\n'` - you have to split it on your own. `ImageFont` should have function to calculate text width for selected font and size. You can run loop which check text width for partial text.

Comment: see `ImageFont.getbbox()` and `ImageFont.getlength()` in [ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont) has `getlength(text)` and `getbbox(text)` which gives text length for selected font and size. You can use to split text to lines.

I first split all text to words and I add next word to text and check `getlength(text)`. If it is shorter then I check with next word. If it is longer then I add this line to results and start with empty text to create new line.

```
width, height = my_image.size

text_test = "Don't be part of the problem, be the whole problem"

all_words = text_test.split(' ')
all_lines = []
line = []

while all_words:
    word = all_words[0]
    new_text = ' '.join(line + [word])
    #print('>', word, new_text)

    if title_font.getlength(new_text) > width:
        # if longer then keep shorter line and start with new line
        all_lines.append(' '.join(line))
        line = []
    else:
        # if shorter then add word to line, and remove word from list 
        line += [word]
        all_words = all_words[1:]
   
# add last line to results 
if line:
    all_lines.append(' '.join(line))
print(all_lines)
```

And next I can use `for`-loop to draw lines:

```
x = 0
y = 500
for text in all_lines:
    #x = (width - title_font.getlength(text))//2
    image_editable.text((x, y), text, (255, 255, 255), align='center', font=title_font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='black')
    y += 100
```

---

Full working code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

my_image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
my_image = my_image.resize((1080,1080))

width, height = my_image.size

title_font = ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', 100)

text_test = "Don't be part of the problem, be the whole problem"

all_words = text_test.split(' ')
all_lines = []
line = []
while all_words:
    word = all_words[0]
    new_text = ' '.join(line + [word])
    print('>', word, new_text)
    if title_font.getlength(new_text) > width:
        all_lines.append(' '.join(line))
        line = []
    else:
        line += [word]
        all_words = all_words[1:]
    
if line:
    all_lines.append(' '.join(line))
print(all_lines)    

image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)

title_text = "Sigma Male Rule #1"
image_editable.text((200, 400), title_text, (255, 255, 255), font=title_font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='black')

y = 500
for text in all_lines:
    image_editable.text((0, y), text, (255, 255, 255), align='center', font=title_font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='black')
    y += 100

my_image.save("result.jpg")

my_image.show()
```

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

Result:
[image]

---

**BTW:**

You can use `getlength()` and `getbbox()` also to test text with different font size to get text which fit in one line.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. I'd upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: BTW: You can use `getlength()` and `getbbox()` also to test text with different font size to get text which fit in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess im doing more or less the same as furas
The difference is that I compare line length. For this to work you have to split at \n as the length is not calculated on wrapped text.

So you split the wraps, compare the length, select the longest line, increase font size until it matches the image size. Thats it.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

my_image = Image.open("image.jpg")
font = ImageFont.truetype('ANTQUAB.TTF', 10)
title_text = "Sigma Male Rule #1"
content_text = 'Don\'t be part of the problem,\nbe the whole problem'
font_size = 10

while True:
    title_size = font.getlength(title_text)
    content_size = font.getlength(content_text)
    text_length = 0
    for line in content_text.split('\n'):
        if len(line) > text_length:
            text_length = len(line)
            content_size = font.getlength(line)

    size = title_size if title_size > content_size else content_size
    if size >= 1060:
        break
    font_size += 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype('ANTQUAB.TTF', font_size)

image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((200, 400), title_text, (255, 255, 255), font=font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='black',
                    align='center')
image_editable.text((0, 500), content_text, (255, 255, 255), align='center', font=font, stroke_width=2,
                    stroke_fill='black')

my_image.save("result.jpg")
```